# How to include transformation in Keras input model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm pretty new to Keras and Tensorflow in general, so perhaps this is a stupid question...

What I want to achieve is the following:
I have a set of words, let's say: cat, dog, cow,..
Those words should be encoded based on a given alphabet, on the position of the character there is a 1 in the vector, else a 0. 
For cat e.g. something like 1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,....,1,0,0,...0.

I use the Keras Tokenizer for that:

```
tk = Tokenizer(char_level=True, oov_token='UNK')

alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzöäü0123456789-,;.!?:'\"/\\|_@#$%^&*~`+-=<>()[]{}"
char_dict = {}
for i, char in enumerate(alphabet):
    char_dict[char] = i + 1

# Use char_dict to replace the tk.word_index
tk.word_index = char_dict 
# Add 'UNK' to the vocabulary 
tk.word_index[tk.oov_token] = max(char_dict.values()) + 1

x_train = tk.texts_to_matrix(x_train)
```

Those vectors are passed into the Keras model for prediction. Now, I want the transformation to happen in the Keras model. So, the user should provide "cat" to the model and not a numeric vector like above. And the model should also return "cat". 
How can I achieve that? I saw that there is a Lambda layer in Keras, is this the correct approach?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit** for clarification:
The model at the moment looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(alphabet)+1,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

But what I want to achieve is to have an input layer that gets strings as inputs and converts the strings to the format the actual first layer can read.Something like this:

```
model = Sequential()
**model.add(transformation_layer)**
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(alphabet)+1,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

**Edit 2**
This is what I tried, but getting the following error when running the "model.fit" function:

*tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function*.

```
def transform_layer(x):
  return tk.texts_to_matrix(x)



print('Building model...')
transform_layer = Lambda(transform_layer)
model = Sequential()
model.add(transform_layer)
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(alphabet)+1,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(np.array(['test','test2']), np.array(['blub','blub2']),
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: You can split each word into its characters. Then with sklearn's `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()` you can create a one-hot encoding for each word.

Comment: You want to feed strings to your model instead of numbers? Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, I want to feed strings to the model. The input layer should do the transformation that is shown above.